# Slack (via Oauth) chat.postMessage Error, "channel_not_found", Even Though Channel Is Present

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, slack-api

When I test out `chat.postMessage` using [Slack's tester](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test) plus a legacy token everything works correctly as seen in the 1st screenshot below.

However, when I try a POST request via Postman using my oauth workspace access token a `channel_not_found` error gets kicked back even though I am using the same exact channel ID (`C9FEK4T0D`). The bottom screenshot shows my setup in Postman. Per Slack [specs](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth), I am placing my access tokens in the request's Authorization HTTP header.

*What am I not including or doing incorrectly that's resulting in the error?*

BTW, not sure if it matters but `chat.postMessage` gets invoked via a slash command.

---

**`chat.postMessage` Test Screenshot:**

[image: chat.postMessage Test screenshot confirmation]

---

**Screenshot of POST request to `chat.postMessage` using request via Postman:**

[image]

Comment: maybe your token has no access to that channel? workspace tokens can be limited. you can check the permissions of your workspace token with. https://api.slack.com/methods/apps.permissions.info  Or user a classic user token, since workspace tokens are still "in preview = beta"

Comment: It appears that my workspace token is valid and does include the channel. https://i.imgur.com/fcQyBza.png

Comment: Just in case you were going to ask, here's a list of scope my app has access to. https://i.imgur.com/icgjBPL.png

Comment: @ErikKalkoken you were right about the workspace tokens being in beta. I finished my application the day Slack announced they were halting the program. Good times. But on the bright side I got the temporary access token working. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW the solution to the issue I was having with regards to this OP was that I was mixing a custom header with arguments in the params. I removed the params and put the arguments in the `body` of the request.

Comment: cool. would be awesome if you could post the solution as answer

Comment: I've been trying to use Postman but it's not working ever since I migrated to 6.4.2 earlier today. Once I can rectify this I'll post a solution w/ screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the params to the body it resolved the issue. I was mixing params with a header which is a no no.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new Slack Bot Token Scopes, make sure that you are also using the `Bot User OAuth Access Token` and not the legacy user-based `OAuth Access Token`.

The `OAuth Access Token` will not fail immediately, but will always be restricted by the rights of the user who requested the app installation. This results in IMs between the bot user and other workspace users not being visible.

[image]